# How to wget a file to a remote machine over SSH?

Tags: ssh, wget

I'd like to basically pipe a `wget` command to a file on a remote server over SSH. How can I do this? I know I could simply `ssh` into the server and have it download the file, but I'd much rather use the local machine to download it and send it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

So you are logged into a machine `myclient` and have `ssh` access to another machine `myserver`. You want to download a file over HTTP from a remove server `www.example.com` to `myclient` but the data needs to be *saved* on `myserver`. This should do it:

```
wget -O - http://www.example.com/whatever | ssh myserver 'cat >/path/to/remote/destination'
```

Alternatively, you could mount the `myserver`'s filesystem over SSH with [sshfs](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html). This may be too much hassle for a one-off need, but convenient if you do this sort of thing often.

```
mkdir ~/myserver
sshfs myserver:/ ~/myserver
wget -O ~/myserver/path/to/remote/destination http://www.example.com/whatever
```

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I wanted to do. I needed to run the actual HTTP download on `A`, but copy the file over SSH to `B` without actually storing the file on `A`. Win!