# how to download a file using just bash and nothing else (no curl, wget, perl, etc.)

Tags: bash, command-line, web

I have a minimal headless *nix which **does not have** any command line utilities for downloading files (e.g. no curl, wget, etc).  I only have bash.

How can I download a file?

Ideally, I would like a solution that would work across a wide range of *nix.

Comment: how about `gawk`

Comment: I can't remember now if gawk was available, though I'd love to see a gawk based solution if you have one :)

Comment: here's an example: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawkinet/gawkinet.html#Web-page

Answer (score 79, accepted):

If you have bash 2.04 or above with the `/dev/tcp` pseudo-device enabled, you can download a file from bash itself.

Paste the following code directly into a bash shell (you don't need to save the code into a file for executing):

```
function __wget() {
    : ${DEBUG:=0}
    local URL=$1
    local tag="Connection: close"
    local mark=0

    if [ -z "${URL}" ]; then
        printf "Usage: %s \"URL\" [e.g.: %s http://www.google.com/]" \
               "${FUNCNAME[0]}" "${FUNCNAME[0]}"
        return 1;
    fi
    read proto server path <<<$(echo ${URL//// })
    DOC=/${path// //}
    HOST=${server//:*}
    PORT=${server//*:}
    [[ x"${HOST}" == x"${PORT}" ]] && PORT=80
    [[ $DEBUG -eq 1 ]] && echo "HOST=$HOST"
    [[ $DEBUG -eq 1 ]] && echo "PORT=$PORT"
    [[ $DEBUG -eq 1 ]] && echo "DOC =$DOC"

    exec 3<>/dev/tcp/${HOST}/$PORT
    echo -en "GET ${DOC} HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: ${HOST}\r\n${tag}\r\n\r\n" >&3
    while read line; do
        [[ $mark -eq 1 ]] && echo $line
        if [[ "${line}" =~ "${tag}" ]]; then
            mark=1
        fi
    done <&3
    exec 3>&-
}
```

Then you can execute it as from the shell as follows:

```
__wget http://example.iana.org/
```

Source: [Moreaki](https://superuser.com/users/168962/moreaki)'s answer [upgrading and installing packages through the cygwin command line?](https://superuser.com/questions/40545/upgrading-and-installing-packages-through-the-cygwin-command-line/496572#496572)

**Update:**
as mentioned in the comment, the approach outlined above is simplistic:

- the `read` will trashes backslashes and leading whitespace.
- Bash can't deal with NUL bytes very nicely so binary files are out.
- unquoted `$line` will glob.

Comment: So you answered your own question at the same time as you asked it. That's an interesting time machine you have ;)

Comment: @MeerBorg - when you ask a question, look for the tick box 'answer your own question' - http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Comment: @eestartup - I don't think you can vote for your own answer.  Can I explain the code?  Not yet!   But it does work on cygwin.

Comment: Just a note: This won't work with some configurations of Bash. I believe Debian configures this feature out of their distribution of Bash.

Comment: @EvanTeitelman, :) From Debian BT [bash: PATCH support TCP/UDP service names](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=65172), [bash: net redirections doesn't work](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=66352), [Error in bash manpage](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=313538), [bash: /dev/tcp should be enabled by default](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=146464). [Seems this feature was enabled long time ago](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=146464#37)

Comment: [Is there a real reason to disable this?](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=66352#10): This kind of feature should not be part of a shell but a special. tool. And
that tool has existed for years already, it's called netcat.:)

Comment: Urgh, while this is a nice trick, it can too easily cause corrupt downloads. `while read` like that trashes backslashes and leading whitespace and Bash can't deal with NUL bytes very nicely so binary files are out. And unquoted `$line` will glob ... None of this I see mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @ilkkachu, can you see 131's answer below?  I thought it should fail on null bytes for the same reason you state here, but it *seems* to work.

Comment: if you copy the function into your .bashrc (as you should, NEVER just paste a function pure into the shell) , you will have it  available at shell-spawn. alternatively, why not just use c++ or python, should ship with most *nix derivates, right?

Answer (score 23):

Use lynx.

It is pretty common for most of Unix/Linux.

```
lynx -dump http://www.google.com
```

-dump: dump the first file to stdout and exit

```
man lynx
```

Or netcat:

```
/usr/bin/printf 'GET / \n' | nc www.google.com 80
```

Or telnet:

```
(echo 'GET /'; echo ""; sleep 1; ) | telnet www.google.com 80
```

Comment: The OP has "*nix which does not have any command line utilities for downloading files", so no lynx for sure.

Comment: Note `lynx -source` is closer to wget

Comment: Hey, so this is a really late comment but how do you save the output of the telnet command to a file? Redirecting with ">" outputs both the file's contents and telnet output such as "Trying 93.184.216.34... Connected to www.example.com.". I'm in a situation where I can only use telnet, I'm trying to make a chroot jail with the least frameworks possible.

Answer (score 19):

Adapted from [Chris Snow's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83927/80216). 
This can also handle binary files.

```
function __curl() {
  read -r proto server path <<<"$(printf '%s' "${1//// }")"
  if [ "$proto" != "http:" ]; then
    printf >&2 "sorry, %s supports only http\n" "${FUNCNAME[0]}"
    return 1
  fi
  DOC=/${path// //}
  HOST=${server//:*}
  PORT=${server//*:}
  [ "${HOST}" = "${PORT}" ] && PORT=80

  exec 3<>"/dev/tcp/${HOST}/$PORT"
  printf 'GET %s HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: %s\r\n\r\n' "${DOC}" "${HOST}" >&3
  (while read -r line; do
   [ "$line" = $'\r' ] && break
  done && cat) <&3
  exec 3>&-
}
```

- I `break && cat` to get out of `read`.
- I use HTTP 1.0 so there's no need to wait for/send a connection:close.

You can test binary files like this:

```
$ __curl http://www.google.com/favicon.ico >   mine.ico
$ curl   http://www.google.com/favicon.ico > theirs.ico
$ md5sum mine.ico theirs.ico
f3418a443e7d841097c714d69ec4bcb8  mine.ico
f3418a443e7d841097c714d69ec4bcb8  theirs.ico
```

Comment: This won't handle binary transfer files—it will fail on null bytes.

Comment: @Wildcard, i do not understand , i've edited with a binary file transfer example (containing null bytes), can you point me what i'm missing ?

Comment: @Wildcard, heheh, yeah that looks like it should work, since it reads the actual file data with `cat`. I'm not sure if that's cheating (since it's not _purely_ the shell), or a nice solution (since `cat` is a standard tool, after all). But @131, you might want to add a note about why it works better than the other solutions here.

Comment: @Wildcard, I added the pure bash solution too as an answer below. And yes, cheating or not, this is a valid solution and worth an upvote :)

Answer (score 17):

Taking the "*just Bash and **nothing** else*" strictly, here's one adaptation of earlier answers ([@Chris's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83927/170373), [@131's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/421318/170373)) that does not call any external utilities (not even standard ones) but also works with binary files:

```
#!/bin/bash
download() {
  read proto server path <<< "${1//"/"/ }"
  DOC=/${path// //}
  HOST=${server//:*}
  PORT=${server//*:}
  [[ x"${HOST}" == x"${PORT}" ]] && PORT=80

  exec 3<>/dev/tcp/${HOST}/$PORT

  # send request
  echo -en "GET ${DOC} HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: ${HOST}\r\n\r\n" >&3

  # read the header, it ends in a empty line (just CRLF)
  while IFS= read -r line ; do 
      [[ "$line" == $'\r' ]] && break
  done <&3

  # read the data
  nul='\0'
  while IFS= read -d '' -r x || { nul=""; [ -n "$x" ]; }; do 
      printf "%s$nul" "$x"
  done <&3
  exec 3>&-
}
```

Use with `download http://path/to/file > file`.

We deal with NUL bytes with `read -d ''`. It reads until a NUL byte, and returns true if it found one, false if it didn't. Bash can't handle NUL bytes in strings, so when `read` returns with true, we add the NUL byte manually when printing, and when it returns false, we know there are no NUL bytes any more, and this should be the last piece of data.

Tested with Bash 4.4 on files with NULs in the middle, and ending in zero, one or two NULs, and also with the `wget` and `curl` binaries from Debian. The 373 kB `wget` binary took about 5.7 seconds to download. A speed of about 65 kB/s or a bit more than 512 kb/s.

In comparison, @131's cat-solution finishes in less than 0.1 s, or almost a hundred times faster. Not very surprising, really.

This is obviously silly, since without using external utilities, there's not much we can do with the downloaded file, not even make it executable.

Comment: Isn't  echo a standalone -non shell- binary ? (:p)

Comment: @131, no! Bash has `echo` and `printf` as builtins (it needs a builtin `printf` to implement `printf -v`)

Comment: Worked great for me. Used it to download a statically compiled `curl` to do the further requests with that.

Comment: @stempler, thanks for reminding me I've created this monster. You really should have used one of the other ones. :P

Comment: @DanielLe, re. the edit, I'm not exactly sure why you'd like to remove the quotes from the parameter expansion there and the linked post also doesn't state any reason. I've tested this in Bash, and it works with the quotes (and also without). In other shells, the results vary, but the `"${a//// }"` variant only works in Bash and Busybox, while `"${a//\// }"` works in all shells I tried. The one with quotes doesn't work in zsh or Busybox though, but it doesn't matter that much since the whole exercise only works in Bash anyway.

Comment: (A similar function could likely be built for zsh, and more easily since it does support NULs in variables directly unlike Bash and most other shells.)

Comment: now, if we were to change that, it'd likely be better to just replace it with `IFS=/ read ... <<< "$1"` as that wouldn't require substituting slashes back for `DOC` on the very next line...

Comment: @ikkachu I suggested edits to remove the quotes because I tested this answer in Bash and the current version didn't work: https://pastebin.com/CQw1PUnh

Comment: @DanielLe, hmm, I can't replicate that with Bash 5.x. I just pulled 5.2.15(1) from the source tarball and tested it. The only difference I can see is that with Bash 3.2 (which Macs have by default), the version with quotes indeed doesn't work. See what you get if you put `echo $BASH_VERSION` inside the function?

Comment: @ikkachu `$ echo $BASH_VERSION 3.2.57(1)-release`. You're right, the current version works in Bash v5.x but not in Bash v3.2.x, which is the default in Ventura v13.2 :) I had Bash v5.x installed via Homebrew recently, but the shell I ran in https://pastebin.com/CQw1PUnh was v3.2.x :)

Answer (score 9):

**Use uploading instead, via SSH from your local machine**

A "minimal headless *nix" box means you probably SSH into it. So you can also use SSH to *upload* to it. Which is functionally equivalent to downloading (of software packages etc.) *except* when you want a download command to include in a script on your headless server of course.

As shown in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/9033), you would execute the following on your *local* machine to place a file on your remote headless server:

```
wget -O - http://example.com/file.zip | ssh user@host 'cat >/path/to/file.zip'
```

**Faster uploading via SSH from a third machine**

The disadvantage of the above solution compared to downloading is lower transfer speed, since the connection with your local machine usually has much less bandwidth than the connection between your headless server and other servers.

To solve that, you can of course execute the above command on another server with decent bandwidth. To make that more comfortable (avoiding a manual login on the third machine), here is a command to execute *on your local machine*.

To be secure, copy & paste that command *including the leading space character* `' '`. See the explanations below for the reason.

```
 ssh user@intermediate-host "sshpass -f <(printf '%s\n' yourpassword) \
   ssh -T -e none \
     -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no \
     < <(wget -O - http://example.com/input-file.zip) \
     user@target-host \
     'cat >/path/to/output-file.zip' \
"
```

Explanations:

- The command will ssh to your third machine `intermediate-host`, start downloading a file to there via `wget`, and start uploading it to `target-host` via SSH. Downloading and uploading use the bandwidth of your `intermediate-host` and happen at the same time (due to Bash pipe equivalents), so progress will be fast.
- When using this, you have to replace the two server logins (`user@*-host`), the target host password (`yourpassword`), the download URL (`http://example.com/…`) and the output path on your target host (`/path/to/output-file.zip`) with appropriate own values.
- For the `-T -e none` SSH options when using it to transfer files, see [these detailed explanations](http://inai.de/linux/usr_sshpipe).
- This command is meant for cases where you can't use SSH's public key authentication mechanism – it still happens with some shared hosting providers, [notably Host Europe](https://faq.hosteurope.de/?cpid=19045). To still automate the process, we rely on `sshpass` to be able to supply the password in the command. It requires `sshpass` to be installed on your intermediate host (`sudo apt-get install sshpass` under Ubuntu).
- We try to use `sshpass` in a secure way, but it will still not be as secure as the SSH pubkey mechanism (says `man sshpass`). In particular, we supply the SSH password not as a command line argument but via a file, which is replaced by bash process substitution to make sure it never exists on disk. The `printf` is a bash built-in, making sure this part of the code does not pop up as a separate command in `ps` output as that would expose the password [[source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24454037/pass-a-password-to-ssh-in-pure-bash#comment62638852_24455773)]. I *think* that this use of `sshpass` is just as secure as the `sshpass -d<file-descriptor>` variant recommended in `man sshpass`, because bash maps it internally to such a `/dev/fd/*` file descriptor anyway. And that without using a temp file [[source](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/181937/how-create-a-temporary-file-in-shell-script#comment303188_181996)]. But no guarantees, maybe I overlooked something.
- Again to make the `sshpass` usage safe, we need to prevent the command from being recorded to the bash history on your local machine. For that, the whole command is prepended with one space character, which has this effect.
- The `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` part prevents the command from failing in case it never connected to the target host. (Normally, SSH would then wait for user input to confirm the connection attempt. We make it proceed anyway, to not have an indefinitely hanging command on the intermediate host.)
- `sshpass` expects a `ssh` or `scp` command as its last argument. So we have to rewrite the typical `wget -O - … | ssh …` command into a form without a bash pipe, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22019615).

Answer (score 7):

Based on [Chris Snow's script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/83927/80216).  I made some improvements:

- http scheme check (it only supports http)
- http response validation (response status line check,
  and split header and body by '\r\n' line,
  not 'Connection: close' which is not true sometimes)
- failed on non-200 code (it's important to download files on the internet)

Here is the code:

```
function __wget() {
    : "${DEBUG:=0}"
    local URL=$1
    local tag="Connection: close"

    if [ -z "${URL}" ]; then
        printf "Usage: %s \"URL\" [e.g., %s http://www.google.com/]" \
               "${FUNCNAME[0]}" "${FUNCNAME[0]}"
        return 1;
    fi  
    read -r proto server path <<< "$(printf '%s' "${URL//// }")"
    local SCHEME=${proto//:*}
    local PATH=/${path// //} 
    local HOST=${server//:*}
    local PORT=${server//*:}
    if [[ "$SCHEME" != "http" ]]; then
        printf "sorry, %s only supports http\n" "${FUNCNAME[0]}"
        return 1
    fi  
    [[ "${HOST}" == "${PORT}" ]] && PORT=80
    [[ "$DEBUG" -eq 1 ]] && echo "SCHEME=$SCHEME" >&2
    [[ "$DEBUG" -eq 1 ]] && echo "HOST=$HOST"     >&2
    [[ "$DEBUG" -eq 1 ]] && echo "PORT=$PORT"     >&2
    [[ "$DEBUG" -eq 1 ]] && echo "PATH=$PATH"     >&2

    if ! exec 3<>"/dev/tcp/${HOST}/$PORT"; then
        return "$?"
    fi  
    
    if ! echo -en "GET ${PATH} HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: ${HOST}\r\n${tag}\r\n\r\n" >&3 ; then
        return "$?"
    fi  
    # 0: at begin, before reading http response
    # 1: reading header
    # 2: reading body
    local state=0
    local num=0
    local code=0
    while read -r line; do
        num=$((num + 1))
        # check http code
        if [ "$state" -eq 0 ]; then
            if [ "$num" -eq 1 ]; then
                if [[ $line =~ ^HTTP/1\.[01][[:space:]]([0-9]{3}).*$ ]]; then
                    code="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
                    if [[ "$code" != "200" ]]; then
                        printf "failed to wget '%s', code is not 200 (%s)\n" \
                               "$URL" "$code"
                        exec 3>&-
                        return 1
                    fi
                    state=1
                else
                    printf "invalid http response from '%s'" "$URL"
                    exec 3>&-
                    return 1
                fi
            fi
        elif [ "$state" -eq 1 ]; then
            if [[ "$line" == $'\r' ]]; then
                # found "\r\n"
                state=2
            fi
        elif [ "$state" -eq 2 ]; then
            # redirect body to stdout
            # TODO: any way to pipe data directly to stdout?
            echo "$line"
        fi
    done <&3
    exec 3>&-
}
```

Comment: Nice enhancements +1

Comment: It worked, But I found a concern, when I use this scripts, It keep wait several seconds when all data is read finished, this case not happen in @Chris Snow answer, anyone could explain this?

Comment: And, in this answer, ``echo -en "GET ${PATH} HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: ${HOST}\r\n${tag}\r\n\r\n" >&3``,  ``${tag}`` is not specified.

Comment: I edit this answer with ``tag`` variable is correct set, it work well now.

Comment: not working with zsh , __wget http://www.google.com
sorry,  only support http
/usr/bin/env: bash: No such file or directory

Answer (score 5):

If you have this package libwww-perl

You can simply use:

```
/usr/bin/GET
```

Comment: Considering that other answers don't respect the question requirement (bash only), I think this is actually better than the `lynx` solution, as Perl is surely more likely to be preinstalled that Lynx.

Answer (score 0):

If you have python2:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 -c "import sys; import urllib2; exec('try: response = urllib2.urlopen(\'http://localhost:8080/ping\');\nexcept Exception as e: sys.exit(1)')"
```