# Can `fetch` retrieve only headers?

Tags: command-line, web

For `$url` being the placeholder for an URL.

`curl` can retrieve headers for an url using

```
#> curl -sI -L $url.
```

`wget` can do the same using:

```
#> wget --server-response --spider $url
```

`fetch` is the third command line downloading tool that I am aware of.

Can it also get only headers?

Comment: According to freeBSD man pages ( https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?fetch(1) ), this tool doesn't seem to allow you to get the headers only.

Comment: Does it really matter? You already have two tools performing the requested operation, do you need a third one?

Comment: Because this code in question is for deployment on systems that are guaranteed to have at least one of `wget`, `curl` or `fetch`.

Comment: Considering headers are always separated from body by a single empty line, are you able to pass the tool output through another tool that will drop everything after the headers (e.g. `sed`)?

Comment: @BLayer no, because the total response (including the body) might be very large. (where as the headers will be very small)

Comment: The download would be terminated after the headers are seen.

Comment: really? Then yes.
Other options are doing something like: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/365365/18637  but substituting "HEAD" for "GET"

Comment: Potential problem with HEAD is that not all servers support it but if you are working with a known, finite number of servers and they all have HEAD then by all means use it.

Comment: By any chance do the servers that you have to use `fetch` with have `netcat` (sometimes `nc` or `ncat`) installed? It's a fairly common tool and if it's there I can tell you how to do HEAD with that. `fetch` is looking to be pretty limited.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a way to fetch the full HTTP page, headers and body, then you could just use this:

```
fetch ... | sed '/^\r$/q'
```

Because [headers are always separated from body by CRLF](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html) this will terminate after retrieving the headers.

Comment: Thanks.
So is it possible to tell `fetch` to use `HEAD` ?
It seems like otherwise the first part is not connected by much to the second.

Comment: You said "other options are...substituting HEAD for GET". When someone says something's an "option" that typically means it's possible. I was just trying to move important information out of the comments into an answer where other people are more likely to see it. If HEAD is not _really_ an option then I need to remove it from my answer.

Comment: To my knowledge you can't trigger HEAD directly from the command line?
the "..." in your quotes covers the part where is links to another post detailing a method where possibly HEAD can be used. This question is about `fetch` however, so if it is not usable with `fetch` then I'm not sure it is worth highlighting. I wouldn't know if it was usable by fetch (thus this question). I assume as the answerer you are more familiar with fetch than I am.

Comment: I don't have access to fetch. I posted my answer as a hopefully helpful suggestion (based on a sound principle) that you could look into since no other answers have been offered. I can't tell from looking at the man page whether full HTTP message is returned.